# Date Grouping Issue- Client Operation Mode- Telerik

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

In client operation mode, when i try to group on date it doesn't work properly the issue can be reproduced in demo also. I have attached the screenshot of demo page. In server mode i get the result as expected. I ve posted the question on telerik forum also but didn't get any response yet

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look at exact date in SQL Server for order 10250 and 10251 ?

If both on same date but if time is diffrence and select query does not properly return date ( return only date part instead of DateandTime) as see. It will solve your problem.

Comment: then why it groups in case of server side and other thing in my dev i set the time exactly same for two records. the problem remains same. I already tried to return the datepart